# How do I make a boolean mask depending on the length of each subitem in the list? Or how do I filter out all strings longer than x?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with amazons reviews of movies. However, I have discovered that some of the name of the movies has been corrupted and are just a huge mess. Since the dataset is pretty big I need to filter out these names somehow. My thinking is, since the ones I have spotted with my eyes are about 1 page long (the namnes that is) to remove all movies that has a name with `len(Data["title"] > 200`.

I tried doing this by just slicing the `df` to get the `asin` (ID) for all the reviews with this moive with the following code.

```
titlesData.loc[len(titlesData["title"]) > 200, "asin"]
```

But since `len(titlesData["title"]) > 200` do not create a mask as I want but just return true since the `df` has more than 200 rows, I currently need some help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) for filter by length of letters:

```
titlesData.loc[titlesData["title"].str.len() > 200, "asin"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
titlesData.loc[len(titlesData["title"].str) < 200]
```

Incase the `dtype` is 'O' just convert it to `str`:

```
titlesData['titles'] = titlesData['titles'].astype(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `map`

```
titlesData.loc[titlesData["title"].map(len) > 200, "asin"]
```